# List comprehension with filtering

Tags: python, django

I have a model in django, where one guy has 1-6 round results for each fight. I'm trying to get all of his fights, then sort them by round. However, some rounds are being skipped:

```
results = self.objects.filter(boxer)
fight_results = []
for r in results:
   result = sorted([x for x in results if x.fight_id == r.fight_id],key=lambda r: -r.round)
   fight_results.append(result)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, for each fight, there are 1 to 6 entries with the same fight_id but different round numbers in a database. I'm just trying to get them all, add to a list and sort by round number

Comment: Can you invert this and store `{fight_id: (x, r)}`?

Comment: I'm not sure what's up with your `key`, I don't think you want to use `r` for that.

Comment: I think you are going to need to explain your database schema and your expected results a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the class/data structure for your `fights` and `rounds` it is difficult to comprehend what you are trying to do. From your description it seems to me that the list comprehension that is being sorted is using `results` incorrectly. Looking at the key being passed tp `sorted` it should be referencing the fights in a particular result and hence should be something like:

```
result = sorted([x for x in r.fights if x.fight_id == r.fight_id],key=lambda r: -r.round)
```